# Where can I find Ionic components images for UI design?

Tags: interface-design, mobile

For testing different UI combinations for an Ionic mobile application I have been asked to provide a Ionic components image kit so they can be drag&drop into Photoshop or other editor.

I have been trying to find it without success. Do someone know if this exists and where it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can buy them from various online shops like [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/) & [GraphicRiver](https://graphicriver.net).Here are some useful UI Kit Links(Free & Premium)

1. Free IONIC UI kit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ztg06dononfuz4/ionic-ui-kit.psd
2. Premium UI Kits Link: https://creativemarket.com/search/ui/kit/Ionic

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting someone posted a large free asset kit on the Affinity forums site for use with Affinity Designer with some version of the Ionic icon set as well as the more-typical freeware iconsets such as entypo+.